# How do I enforce fully bytecode compiling?

Tags: tcl

I am using TCL8.6.8.

Here is my experiment:

```
>cat ~/tmp/1.tcl
proc p {} {
foreach i {a b c} {
    if {$i == "b"} {
        break
    }
    puts $i
}
}
```

Now I come into tclsh:

```
% proc disa {file_name} {
    set f [open $file_name r]
    set data [read -nonewline $f]
    close $f
    tcl::unsupported::disassemble script $data
}

% disa ~/tmp/1.tcl
ByteCode 0x0x55cabfc393b0, refCt 1, epoch 17, interp 0x0x55cabfbdd990 (epoch 17)
  Source "proc p {} {\nforeach i {a b c} {\n    if {$i == \"b\"} ..."
  Cmds 1, src 175, inst 11, litObjs 4, aux 0, stkDepth 4, code/src 1.26
  Code 220 = header 168+inst 11+litObj 32+exc 0+aux 0+cmdMap 4
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-9, src 0-87
  Command 1: "proc p {} {\nforeach i {a b c} {\n    if {$i == \"b\"} ..."
    (0) push1 0     # "proc"
    (2) push1 1     # "p"
    (4) push1 2     # ""
    (6) push1 3     # "\nforeach i {a b c} {\n    if {$i == \"b..."
    (8) invokeStk1 4 
    (10) done
```

You can see that it is not fully compiled to bytecode in that the nesting script of foreach is taken as literal string.

Now I use `tcl::unsupported::disassemble proc` instead of `tcl::unsupported::disassemble script`, I can get a fully bytecode compiled version:

```
% source ~/tmp/1.tcl

% tcl::unsupported::disassemble proc p
ByteCode 0x0x55cabfc393b0, refCt 1, epoch 17, interp 0x0x55cabfbdd990 (epoch 17)
  Source "\nforeach i {a b c} {\n    if {$i == \"b\"} {\n        ..."
  File "/home/jibin/tmp/1.tcl" Line 1
  Cmds 4, src 76, inst 54, litObjs 4, aux 1, stkDepth 5, code/src 4.21
  Code 320 = header 168+inst 54+litObj 32+exc 28+aux 16+cmdMap 16
  Proc 0x0x55cabfc72820, refCt 1, args 0, compiled locals 1
      slot 0, scalar, "i"
  Exception ranges 1, depth 1:
      0: level 0, loop, pc 7-47, continue 49, break 50
  Commands 4:
      1: pc 0-52, src 1-74        2: pc 7-41, src 25-60
      3: pc 23-36, src 50-54        4: pc 42-47, src 66-72
  Command 1: "foreach i {a b c} {\n    if {$i == \"b\"} {\n        br..."
    (0) push1 0     # "a b c"
    (2) foreach_start 0 
        [jumpOffset=-42, vars=[%v0]]
  Command 2: "if {$i == \"b\"} {\n        break\n ..."
    (7) startCommand +34 1  # next cmd at pc 41, 1 cmds start here
    (16) loadScalar1 %v0    # var "i"
    (18) push1 1    # "b"
    (20) eq 
    (21) jumpFalse1 +18     # pc 39
  Command 3: "break..."
    (23) startCommand +14 1     # next cmd at pc 37, 1 cmds start here
    (32) jump4 +18  # pc 50
    (37) jump1 +4   # pc 41
    (39) push1 2    # ""
    (41) pop 
  Command 4: "puts $i..."
    (42) push1 3    # "puts"
    (44) loadScalar1 %v0    # var "i"
    (46) invokeStk1 2 
    (48) pop 
    (49) foreach_step 
    (50) foreach_end 
    (51) push1 2    # ""
    (53) done
```

Here is my question: Why doesn't `tcl::unsupported::disassemble script` fully compile the script? `foreach` command is inside a proc, I'd imagine that the compiling function of `proc` invokes the compiling function of each command, so the compiling function of `foreach` command is invoked regardless.

Comment: I'm curious: _why_ do you want this?

Answer (score 1):

Tcl postpones the compilation of a script or procedure until the first time the bytecoded version of the script/procedure is needed. Compilation is fairly fast (and cached carefully, where that makes sense) and the optimizer in 8.6 is lightweight (just killing some of the stupider code sequences that used to be generated), so this isn't typically a big problem. The degree of compilation done for a particular command varies a lot: `expr` is almost always deeply compiled (if possible!) and `proc` *itself* is never compiled; what you're seeing in the disassembly is generic command call compilation (push the words on the stack, call a generic command with that many words, job done). This makes sense because most calls of `proc` happen once only and only really set things up for interesting things to happen later. The chances of us changing `proc` *itself* to gain deep compilation (as opposed to the procedures it creates) are zero, at least for 8.7/9.0 and probably well ahead there. There's just no win possible to justify the work it would take.

However, if you want to trigger procedure compilation early, you *can*. All it takes is a little triggering…

```
trace add execution proc leave {apply {{cmdArgs code result op} {
    if {$code == 0} {
        # proc succeeded; it must have been called as: proc name args body
        set procedureName [lindex $cmdArgs 1]
        # Make sure we resolve the procedure name in the right namespace!
        set compTime [lindex [time {
             uplevel 1 [list tcl::unsupported::getbytecode proc $procedureName]
        }] 0]
        # We're done now! Totally optional print of how long it took…
        puts stderr "Compiled $procedure in $compTime µs"
    }
}}}
```

I *think* that `getbytecode` is a little faster than `disassemble` (it's doing the same general thing but produces machine-readable output) but I might be wrong. You'll need to use `disassemble` if the code is to be used in 8.5.

Comment: Traces let you do crazy stuff. Execution traces can be _very_ expensive, but aren't on `proc` itself precisely because it is a totally uncompiled command.